# How does spring map post data to POJO?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pojo

I have a spring controller defined like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(User user) {
        // Do something with user
        return "redirect:/...";
    }
}
```

How is post data (data submitted from a form) mapped to the User object in this case? Is there any documentation on how this works?

What happens if I have two POJOs like this?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(User user, Foo anotherPojo) {
        // Do something with user
        return "redirect:/...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, Spring MVC will attempt to match the HTTP POST parameter names to the property names of the `User` class, converting the types of those parameters values as necessary.

In the second case, I believe Spring will throw an exception, since it will only accept one Command object.

Comment: What about post parameters that does not match a property in `User`? Will they just be ignored? Can they be catched with a `@RequestParam("type") type` instead?

Comment: @Richard: They will be ignored, yes, and you can mix and match command objects like User with @RequestParam, in any combination you wish

Answer (score 2):

In many occasions it should be enough if the POST parameter names are the same as you POJO attribute names. The proper way though is to use the [Spring form taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html) and bind it to your pojo:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get() {
        return new ModelAndView().addObject("formBackingObject", new User());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(User user) {
        // Do something with user
        return "redirect:/...";
    }
}
```

And then in your JSP:

```
// e.g in user/login.jsp
<form:form method="post" commandName="formBackingObject" action="/user/login.html">
    <form:label path="username"><spring:message code="label.username" /></form:label>
    <form:input path="username" cssErrorClass="error" />
    <form:label path="password"><spring:message code="label.password" /></form:label>
    <form:password path="password" cssErrorClass="error" />
    <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.login" />"/></p>
</form:form>
```

You can nest your attributes (e.g. address.street if your user has an address property), I don't think Spring will accept more than one command object though.